# What kind of paint can I use to cover wood baseboards?

Tags: wood, painting, baseboard

I mistakenly got white baseboards for a dark wooden floor. The person who made the delivery suggested painting them to match the wood color, however **I'm not sure what kind of paint to use on top of the existing layer.** Latex? Oil based?

The baseboards seem to be pine, and the white paint is a semi-opaque thin layer. Here are some photos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K6zS.jpg - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlar8.jpg

*(This is my first post here so please let me know if I missed anything!)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are standard pre-primed baseboards. Any interior grade latex paint will work.  You do not need primer.  You should not use oil for several reasons:

1. The baseboards are primed already with primer - almost certainly latex based
2. The baseboards are for internal use
3. Oil is a real PITA to use, stinks, and takes forever to dry

Comment: Do you recommend gloss or semi-gloss? Presumably, a DIYer would paint the baseboards before installing them, right? If using a pneumatic nalier use 18 ga brads, fill the holes and touch up. Maybe even get filler which matches the paint color and no touch up painting would be needed.

Comment: When installing baseboards be aware of the water pipes and the drains. It is sometimes not obvious where the pipes are. Go through the house and examine both sides of walls, then put notices on masking tape alerting you of a pipe in the wall.

Comment: Excellent points, thanks @JimStewart and yes, I was planning on painting before installing. Fortunately I (believe I) know where the pipes are because we re-did all the walls.

Comment: Gloss/semi/flat is entirely up to the taste of the person doing the painting.  I prefer painting then installing/touchup since it means less trim edging etc.  Nailing should be done into studs.

Comment: I recommend gloss or semi-gloss. Baseboards get a lot of bumps, dirt, etc. - much harder (in my non-professional opinion) to keep flat paint looking clean, no matter how "washable" it may be.

Comment: @The Evil Greebo, do you nail baseboards into the bottom plate as well as into the studs?

Comment: Sorry I should have said into wood.  Base plates are just fine IMO.  I was really touching on the 'watch where you nail' comment.